# Launch EC2 instance on S3 upload + process file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to automatically launch an EC2 instance whenever a user uploads data to my `datadump-input` S3 bucket. The EC2 instance should then:

1. Start
2. Download the file from `datadump-input` and process it with pre-loaded Python scripts
3. Stop

What's the easiest way to do this? **Specifically, how do I get the file from the S3 bucket to the EC2 instance?** The filename will be different on each upload.

I was thinking Lambda but am open to other services.

Comment: Lambda is perfect fit for this kind of use case.

Comment: @jellycsc I know how to parse the file location from the input. How do I pass that information onto the instance?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by "pass the information onto the instance"?

Comment: How do I make the EC2 instance download the uploaded file from `datadump-input`? It will be a different path every time

Comment: You can use the CLI or SDK to download it from the S3 path.

Comment: @daniel-freeman - Have you checked option of using [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-using-step-functions-to-orchestrate-amazon-emr-workloads/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have S3 send the new object notification to an SQS queue. Configure an auto-scaling group to launch an EC2 instance when the queue depth is greater than 0. On the EC2 instance, have your application poll the SQS queue for messages until there are no more.

Comment: Does SQS let you dynamically pass the location of the S3 file?

Comment: @DanielFreeman I'm not sure I understand your question, for each new object uploaded into S3, S3 will place a message in the SQS queue that contains the bucket and key of the new object as part of the message.

Comment: How I make the EC2 instance download the correct file from the S3 bucket? The filename will be different on each upload

Comment: The filename is the key in S3. The filename would be in the message you get from SQS. You would use that filename to download the file from S3 into the EC2 instance.

Comment: Auto Scaling would be good for launching the instance when messages arrive. However, it would not be great for stopping the instance when messages are processed. To do that, when the instance has finished processing all messages in the queue, it should make an Auto Scaling API call to set the Desired Capacity to zero. This will cause Auto Scaling to stop the instance. When it next starts, it can run a startup script in the `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` directory. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)